# Run both Django and PHP application in Apache

Tags: php, django, configuration, apache2, apache-config

I'm trying to host Django and PHP(wordpress) app in Apache

domain.com, should point to Django app
domain.com/wp, should point to wordpress app

Here is my 000-default.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/wp"
    ServerName domain.com/wp
    Alias /wp /var/www/html/wp
    <Directory /var/www/html/wp>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>                            

<VirtualHost *:80>
        Alias /static /var/www/html/portal/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/portal/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/portal/portal>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess portal python-path=/home/ubuntu/portal:/home/ubuntu/portal/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup portal
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/portal/portal/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

domain.com is taking me to wordpress application.

Can anyone tell me where the issue is or give me a direction to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few issues, first thing is that the ServerName is just a servername and not a url. The second issue is that you should combine the two VirtualHost entries.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName domain.com
    Alias /wp /var/www/html/wp
    <Directory /var/www/html/wp>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /var/www/html/portal/static
    <Directory /var/www/html/portal/static>
                Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # this really should be a sub directory of /var/www/html
    # if your server config follows symlinks, just make a symlink  
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/portal/portal>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess portal python-path=/home/ubuntu/portal:/home/ubuntu/portal/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup portal
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/portal/portal/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This worked, Thanks a lot. I will move the Django app to sub directory of /var/www/html.

Comment: Glad to have helped

Comment: I have my Django app in my home folder. Can I use a symlink under `/var/www/html/` to keep my app in home folder and my php files in `/var/www/html/`?

Comment: @MiniGunnR you will have to carefully set the permissions, but yes, doable

Comment: @e4c5 I am new to this, sorry, do I make a copy of my django project folder with the `ln` command?

Comment: @MiniGunnR  What you want is `ln -s` which creates a symbolic link. Two entries in the directory tree pointing to the same thing

Comment: glad to have been of help @MiniGunnR all the best with your project