# Host both PHP/JS and Django applications with Apache on Windows

Tags: django, apache, wamp

I have a WAMP Server 3.2 (Apache 2.4.46) installed on Windows 10 (64-bits), it is exposed to the local company network. I use it to host ordinary php/js applications. My `httpd-vhosts.conf` is used to look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName RealNameOfTheServer
    DocumentRoot "d:/projects"
    <Directory  "d:/projects/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I got a Django app which preferably needs to be hosted with the same server (since I don't have any other) along with other php applications. I tried to follow the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831508/run-both-django-and-php-application-in-apache) to configure my virtual hosts, but it uses daemon process which is not available on Windows.

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` after applied changes makes Django app work correctly but dumps php/js apps.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName RealNameOfTheServer
    DocumentRoot "d:/projects"
    <Directory  "d:/projects/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "logs/dashboard.error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dashboard.access.log" combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "d:\projects\dashboard\dashboard\wsgi_windows.py"
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    <Directory "d:\projects\dashboard\dashboard">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "d:/projects/dashboard/static"
    <Directory "d:/projects/dashboard/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any way to run both php and Django apps on Windows?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "dumps php/js apps"? What request do you send and what is the reaction?

Comment: I mean that Apache doesn't recognize them as php/js applications and wants to treat them as Django apps applying wsgi_windows.py to them either. If I set "DEBUD = True" in my Django app, so I  get the following error when I try to open a php app. 

Using the URLconf defined in dashboard.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
dashboard/
admin/
The current path, PhPapplication, didn’t match any of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /  "d:\projects\dashboard\dashboard\wsgi_windows.py"
```

will also catch calls to "d:/projects" - so if you want to avoid that, you need to change to something like

```
WSGIScriptAlias /my_wsgi_app/  "d:\projects\dashboard\dashboard\wsgi_windows.py"
```

If you want to avoid that the user can see that, you can use a rewrite rule for certain paths.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. I have tried what you suggested and still can not make it through. My php apps work nicely now. But I can not get Django at place. The url "http://my_server_name/my_wsgi_app/" returns django error: "Using the URLconf defined in dashboard.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

dashboard/
admin/
The empty path didn’t match any of these." 
However, when I try the url "http://my_server_name/my_wsgi_app/dashboard" I get an apache error "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: Ok, I have figure it out! WSGIScriptAlias /my_wsgi_app  "d:\projects\dashboard\dashboard\wsgi_windows.py" makes the job!